# How to get request.user.id value to same function with API query with Python in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm pretty confused with classes and functions in Django, so I'm not sure, if I'm trying to do this right.

1) I have a function, where I do API query. I want to have API-token here from 2) (see below).

```
def API_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    final_url =  urllib2.Request('http://api.website.com', None, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('myusername', 'mypassword')).replace('\n', '')
    final_url.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    readable_json = json.load(json_obj)
    resultsOpen = []
    for i in readable_json:
        resultsOpen.append({
            'subject': i['subject'],
            })
return render(request, 'index/apiTest.html', {'objects_open': resultsOpen)
```

2) I have a class-based-function, where I do query to database and return API-token of current user. This only shows API-token on site now. I want it to be in API-query.

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = User
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['token_list'] = UserTokens.objects.values_list('apiToken', flat=True).get(pk=1)
        return context
```

Both of these work on different templates, but I don't want it. I want to use the API-token variable **context** in the API-query. How I can do this?

edit: Added urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from index.views import UserDetail
from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dbquery/$', UserDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^apitest/$', views.API_search),
]
```

Comment: is `API_search` a view? If so what's the url of it?

Comment: Yes, I added it to question.

Comment: can you show us your `urls.py` too?

Comment: Added urls.py too.

Comment: I don't want to use UserDetail in template, because it only fetch API-token from database, and I don't want to show that on website of course. It's just there for testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a url definition in your `urls.py` which calls the `API_search` function. In your `UserDetailView` store this generated url inside an `href` and when the user clicks on it, call your API search function.

OR

If you want to call the API_Search directly from the `UserDetailView` call a HttpRedirectResponse to that url after generating the proper url.

EDIT: 
Based on the extra information provided, you can use this:

```
def API_search(request):
    user = request.user
    token = UserTokens.objects.values_list('apiToken', flat=True).get(pk=user.id)
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    final_url =  urllib2.Request('http://api.website.com', None, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    #use the token as you like
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('myusername', 'mypassword')).replace('\n', '')
    final_url.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    readable_json = json.load(json_obj)
    resultsOpen = []
    for i in readable_json:
        resultsOpen.append({
            'subject': i['subject'],
            })
return render(request, 'index/apiTest.html', {'objects_open': resultsOpen)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible then do both of these functions in the same view?

Comment: Use both on same view? Ofcourse, just put your `API_Search` code inside your UserDetail view and add that stuff to the context. If that's what you want I will update my answer with the right code

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.